# SKPhysics not working properly?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let None      : UInt32 = 0
    static let All       : UInt32 = UInt32.max
    static let planet    : UInt32 = 0b1    
    static let rocket    : UInt32 = 0b10 }

planet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: planet.size.width / 2)
planet.physicsBody?.dynamic = true planet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.planet
planet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.rocket 
planet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None

func planetCollidedWithRocket(rocket: SKSpriteNode, planet: SKSpriteNode) {
    println("collision planet") }



 func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
        var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
        } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA }

        if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.planet != 0) &&
            (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.rocket != 0)) {
            planetCollidedWithRocket(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, planet: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)}
```

I'm currently using this to add collision detection to my game (I've taken only taken out the bits of code I think are relevant). The first time I ran the game on the simulator it worked fine, and I added a game over scene to the planetCollidedWithRocket method. But I tested it again today and for some reason the game is detecting a collision between the rocket and the planet when they aren't colliding! Can anyone see what Ive done wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your contact isn't set up correctly. This is what you have, and what it translates to:

```
if((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.planet !=0)
// This is checking if the firstBody *has* a categoryBitMask, but it is not evaluating what it is. 
// In addition to that, it is requiring that the PhysicsCategory.planet does not equal zero, which it doesn't. 
// This would evaluate to true every time, no matter what.
// It is also requiring that...


&& (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.rocket != 0))
// This is checking if the secondBody *has* a categoryBitMask, but it is not evaluating what it is.
// In addition to that, it is requiring that the PhysicsCategory.planet does not equal zero, which it doesn't.
// This would evaluate to true every time, no matter what.
```

What you need to do is check that you categoryBitMask *equals* one of your PhysicsCategory variables, such that when a planet and a rocket contact, something evaluates to true. Try this:

```
if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.planet) &&
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.rocket)){

// Code Here

}
```

Alternatively, since you know the hard-coded numbers in your PhysicsCategory struct, you can evaluate to hard numbers:

```
if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == 1) &&
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask == 2)){

// Code Here

}
```

What this will do is check to see if the physicsBody's categoryBitMask equals certain numbers when they contact. If they do, something happens, if not, nothing happens.